# What do wings do on window sash balances and are they important?

Tags: windows

I'm looking to replace my vertical sliding windows sash balances and noticed that they have wings on them. The sashes I looked up online do not have wings, but say they work the same without them. I'm guessing that wings help guide the sash, but I can't find any info about this.

How do the wings affect window operation and are they important?

Here's some examples of the part I am talking about:

[image: Sash with wings]
[image: Sash without wings]

Comment: Maybe the winged ones are for wider grooves in the sashes - the wings fill the extra space? What are the dimensions?

Comment: The sash balancers are 25 inches long and 5/8 inches wide. I don't know how wide the window is, but it's double paned.